# Best way to check if a value is in a multiselectlist?

Tags: multi-select

Sorry if this is a silly question.

But I've been struggling with this for a while.  I want to check if a MultiSelectlist I have contains a particular value.  What is the best way to do this?  I tried using the contains() function, but it doesn't like it.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Never mind, sorted this out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for not having done this earlier. New to SO, what can I say!

I wrote the following script to get the values in the MultiSelectList into an array and post it to an action method using Ajax. I then used the Array.Exists() method in the View to check if the string is in the array or not.

```
    var selValuesArr = [];

    $("#selColList option").each(function (i, current) {
        selValuesArr[i] = $(current).val();
    });
```

Ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Main/Index",
        data: { "selValues": selValuesArr }, //JSON.stringify(selValues) },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#Grid").html(data);
        }
    });
```

And in my View, I have the following function (it takes an int, rather than a string)

```
@functions {
     public bool findColumn(int colId, String[] strArr)
     {
         String temp = colId.ToString() ; 
         if (Array.Exists(strArr, s => s.Equals(temp))) {
             return true; 
         } else {
             return false; 
         }
    }

}
```

HTH